# JSONArray custom request stops working

Tags: android, json, android-activity, android-volley, http-post

In my android app I have a request which until yesterday was working, now it seems ignored by the onCreate. Even if I pass a url to an empty php file, I have no errors, just an empty listview.

Here's my code:

```
public class CustomJsonRequest extends Request<JSONArray> {

    Map<String, String> params;
    customListener listener; 

    public CustomJsonRequest(int requestMethod, String url, Map<String, String> params,
        customListener listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

        super(requestMethod, url, errorListener);
        this.params = params;
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONArray response) {
        listener.onResponse(response); 

    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    }


    @Override
    protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new    
            String(response.data,
            HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }
}
```

In my activity I have the interface and the listeners

My request in the activity is

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    PDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    PDialog.setMessage("..wait..");
    PDialog.show();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.SharedPrefName, 0);
    nome= (prefs.getString("Name", ""));
    genere= (prefs.getString("Sesso",""));
    id= (prefs.getString("ID", ""));
    gps = new GPSTracker(MapActivity.this);
    link= (prefs.getString("LINK", ""));
    age= (prefs.getString("AGE", ""));
    foto= (prefs.getString("FOTO", ""));
       // Get listview
       lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);       
       adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, productsList);
       lv.setAdapter(adapter);
 CustomJsonRequest requi= new CustomJsonRequest(Request.Method.POST,
              url_all_products_post, null, listener, error)
      {protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
          Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
          params.put("id",id);
          params.put("name", nome);
          params.put("gender", genere);
          params.put("lt", lt);
          params.put("ln", ln);
          params.put("age", age);
          params.put("foto", foto);
          params.put("link", link);
          return params;
      };
  };
  // Adding request to request queue
  AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(requi);

}
  public interface customListener{
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response);
}

ErrorListener error = new ErrorListener(){

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }};

customListener listener= new customListener(){

    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

        try {
            // Parsing json array response
            // loop through each json object
             ...
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // notifying list adapter about data changes

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        hidepDialog();
    }
};
```

Why the onCreate "skips" my request?

Comment: I added the onCreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any reason why the below wouldn't work as you would expect.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    PDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    PDialog.setMessage("..wait..");
    PDialog.show();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.SharedPrefName, 0);
    nome = (prefs.getString("Name", ""));
    genere = (prefs.getString("Sesso", ""));
    id = (prefs.getString("ID", ""));
    gps = new GPSTracker(MapActivity.this);
    link = (prefs.getString("LINK", ""));
    age = (prefs.getString("AGE", ""));
    foto = (prefs.getString("FOTO", ""));
    // Get listview
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, productsList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("id", id);
    params.put("name", nome);
    params.put("gender", genere);
    params.put("lt", lt);
    params.put("ln", ln);
    params.put("age", age);
    params.put("foto", foto);
    params.put("link", link);

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(new CustomJsonRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url_all_products_post, params, new customListener() {

        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

            try {
                // Parsing json array response
                // loop through each json object

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // notifying list adapter about data changes

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            hidepDialog();
        }
    }, new ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }));
}
```